# How to read a CSV file that starts with a specific substring in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a CSV file whose name is like:

```
Pokémon_Pikachu.csv.
```

Is there a way to read it if I give only the first substring (Pokémon) and still read it in `Pandas`?

Comment: Sure, but what have you tried?

Comment: pd.read_csv(glob(path.join)).
It gives me an error message Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'list'> type

Comment: have you tried `pikachu I choose you!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-os-listdir-and-endswith

you can use `os.listdir()` to get a list of the contents of a directory, then filter those with `string.startswith(substring)` or `string.endswith(substring)`.

That would give you the filename(s) that you could put into `pd.read_csv(filename)`

Answer (score 7):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob("Pokémon*.csv"):
    print (file)
```

this will get you the csv file names that start with Pokémon
and if you want to read all the csv files into one,

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob("Pokémon*.py"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

print main_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but I suppose that you have files in directory with prefix `Pokémon`. The sollution is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir, 'Pokemon_*.csv')):
    pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: Thank you but I get an error message: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: Repaired. I forgot closing bracket